# Python merge 2 lists / SQL JOIN

Tags: python, join, pandas, merge

If I have 2 lists or data frame (pandas) in python how do I merge / match / join them?

For example:

List / DF 1:

```
Table_Name  Table_Alias
  tab_1          t1
  tab_2          t2
  tab_3          t3
```

List / DF 2:

```
Table_Alias   Variable_Name
    t1            Owner
    t1            Owner_Id
    t2            Purchase_date
    t3            Maintenance_cost
```

Desired Result:

```
Table_Name   Table_Alias   Variable_Name
   tab_1         t1            Owner
   tab_1         t1            Owner_Id
   tab_2         t2            Purchase_date
   tab_3         t3            Maintenance_cost
```

NOTE : If I was doing this in R, I'd use something like:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'Table_Alias', all.y = T)
```

What's the best way to do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an 'outer' [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging):

```
In [9]:
df.merge(df1, how='outer')

Out[9]:
  Table_Name Table_Alias     Variable_Name
0      tab_1          t1             Owner
1      tab_1          t1          Owner_Id
2      tab_2          t2     Purchase_date
3      tab_3          t3  Maintenance_cost
```

It will match on overlapping columns from both dfs and return the union of the matching rows.

Answer (score -1):

I would simply use `pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer',on='alias')`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ "table_name":['tab1',"tab2","tab3"],"talias ['t1','t2','t3']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"talias":['t1',"t1","t2",'t3'], "vname,['Owner','Owner_Id','Purchase_date','Maintenance_cost']})


pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer', on='talias')


Out:
    Table_Alias Table_Name  Variable_Name
0   t1  tab1    Owner
1   t1  tab1    Owner_Id
2   t2  tab2    Purchase_date
3   t3  tab3    Maintenance_cost
```